# jQuery param() function giving this.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code:

```
function parseContent(targetDiv) {
    $("#"+targetDiv+" > [contentName]").each(function (index) {
        var data = $(this).attr("contentData");
        if(data != undefined) {
            alert(data);
            alert(jQuery.param(data));
        }
    })
}
```

It parses some html and looks for elements with contentName as an attribute in them.  For each of those, check to see if there is an attribute contentData, and if so turn the json into parameters.

It's doing the each() just fine. However I get one alert (the first one) prints:

```
{reportId : 5}
```

which is correct, but then fails and in the console i get:

```
TypeError: this.replace is not a function
```

Im pretty sure that is correct JSON format.  I have tried it with adding quotes also  like  {'reportId':5}  but I get the same error;

Any Ideas?

Comment: what does data prints out in your console?

Comment: [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) expects an object but `data` is a string

Comment: @Andreas right. your first alert should return this `[object Object]` not this `{reportId : 5}` who is a string.

Comment: well, if you are sure data is in the right format, JSON.parse(data)
and pass it into jQuery.param(), that is, I suppose the data string is a json format string

Comment: @歐津柏 That's not JSON... Otherwise this would be the way to go. @mmaceachran: Wherever this value is coming from change it to output valid JSON (`{"reportId": 5}`). And use `data-*` instead of custom attributes :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because $.param expects a JSON Object as its parameter and not a string formatted as JSON. So if you pass something like this, it's going to fail:

```
var jsonElement = '{"reportId": 5}';
var result = $.param(jsonElement); //throws exception
```

Instead, if you do:

```
var jsonElement = '{"reportId": 5}';
var result = $.param(JSON.parse(jsonElement));
```